# Is it possible to get JSON from a URL and save it as json file with a custom name inside a specified path/folder through the front end?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

My issue is simple on paper - I have a React Native project and I'm trying to make a script that will run on build and fetch JSON from a URL, then save it as JSON file with a custom name inside a specified path/folder. For example, I want to access the JSON at `www.example.com` and save it as a JSON file in `project/src/assets/locales/en.json`

The problem is that when I google how to fetch and save JSON, most of the results are related to Node.js and I don't think I can use them. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Do you mean React Native Desktop (only)? Since "file system" is a bit of a variable concept in different mobile OSes...

Comment: If I do a search for "["react native" file system](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22react+native%22+file+system)" I find several options. I suspect most if not all relate to RN Desktop (but I wouldn't really know).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What I'm trying to do is not save the JSON file to the device from inside the application, but to the actual project/code so that it can be bundled on build time. The script that will download this JSON file will be called on git pre-push.

Comment: What language/environment are you running the script in? It seems like you probably can use Node.js for this after all (from a git push hook), although you could probably also use a shell script and `curl` or `wget`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder JavaScript and Node.js. I guess if the environment that is gonna run the script is Node.js, I can use the Node.js fs to do the saving?

Comment: Yup! :-) ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said you're doing this in a `git` push hook, you can use any of several things for this:

1. You can indeed use Node.js, by having the hook run it via `node`, and then using Node.js's `http` client (to read it) and `fs` module (to write it to a file).
2. You can use a shell script, perhaps using with `curl` or `wget` (on platforms where those are available).

Since you're already writing JavaScript code for the app itself, Node.js is a reasonable choice.